# Animating with a Video Clip

Tags: animation

I have created an Animation in Blender, with an imported 'stl' file of an airplane that flies over an ocean [Plane w Ocean Modifier] and a blue sky background [checked Background and imported an image of the sky].  The Animation works fine in Camera view; the airplane, Ocean & Sky all show as imported: colors, textures, materials.

In the Video Sequence Editor, I Added a video clip, spliced the clip and inserted a picture image - and it plays just fine.

The problem is the Animation clip.  It only shows the plane flying toward the Camera, with no Ocean below or Sky above.  I am unable to Render the whole video, with the video clip, picture image, and animation sections together - showing all the colors, textures & materials.

How do I get the Animation to show up with the Ocean & Sky?

Comment: Can you share the file or upload some screenshots to provide more information? Did you try to render the animation without using the sequencer first? With "checked Background" do you mean the 3D View Background option in the NPanel? How far is your camera away from your ocean? Could it be a frustum culling problem? Anyway more information would be great.